# Intersection Observer API - Background Image

Tags: javascript, image, performance, lazy-loading

I'm trying to implement the Intersection Observer API for inline background images (for lazy loading). However it's 404ing and returning an undefined error. The reason the background images are inlined is the website runs on WordPress so it needs to pull the images from the media library.

The JS and CSS are in the footer, I've tried putting it in the head but no success. It does work on normal img tags but just not the background images.

Here is the code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="image js-img" style="background-image:url('<?= $image ?>');">
```

**CSS**

```
 .js-img.fade {
    animation-name: fadeIn;
    animation-duration: 400ms;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
}        

@keyframes fadeIn {
    0% { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 1; }
}
```

**JS**

```
const images = document.querySelectorAll('.js-img');

if(!('IntersectionObserver' in window)) {
    images.forEach(image => {
        handleImage(image);
    })
} else {
    let config = {
        rootMargin: '100px 0px',
        threshold: 0.01
    };
    let observer = new IntersectionObserver(observeImages, config);

    images.forEach(image => {
        observer.observe(image);
    }) 

    function observeImages(entries) {
        entries.forEach(entry => {
            if(entry.intersectionRatio > 0) {
                observer.unobserve(entry.target);
                handleImage(entry.target);
            }
        })
    } 
}

function handleImage(el) {
    preloadImage(el.dataset.src).then(src => {
        el.tagName === 'IMG' ?
            el.src = src :
            el.style.backgroundImage = 'url('+ src +')';

        el.classList.add('fade');
        el.removeAttribute('data-src');
    })    
}

function preloadImage(url) {
    return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
        let image = new Image();
        image.load = resolve(url);
        image.error = reject;
        image.src = url;
    })
}
```

Comment: You miss the quote on the line : el.style.backgroundImage = 'url(\''+ src +\'')'; documention here : https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_backgroundimage.asp

Comment: @Shim-Sao Thanks, the rendered HTML is now outputting: `<div class="image js-img fade" style="background-image: url(&quot;+ src +&quot;);">`